# Get around two @AssistedInject in a class

Tags: java, guice

I have a java class having two constructors taking different parameters with two @AssistedInject. I am aware that this is not allowed, do we have any work around for it? This class is an Assistant class, so it is being used throughout the project, I do not want to create a separate Assistant class for the new logic I am writing. I do not prefer passing the assisted parameters as a parameter to the internal methods where it is being used.

```
    @Singleton
            Class Apple {
            }

            Class Assistant {

                private final Apple apple;
                private List<Fruits> rawFruits;
                private List<Fruits> ripeFruit;

                @AssistedInject
                A(final Apple apple, @Assisted List<Fruits> rawFruits) {
                  this.apple = apple;
                  this.rawFruits = rawFruits;
                }

                @AssistedInject
                A(final Apple apple, @Assisted final List<Fruits> rawFruits,@Assisted final List<Fruits> ripeFruits) {

               this.apple = apple;
               this.rawFruits = rawFruits;
               this.ripeFruits = ripeFruits;
         }

         public Fruit getRipeFruits() {
            return ripeFruits.get(0);
         }

        public interface Factory {

         A create(List<Fruits> rawFruits);

         A create(List<Fruits> rawFruits, List<Fruits> ripeFruits>)

        }

     }

GuiceModule

class Module extends AbstractModule {
@Override
protected void configure() {

install(new FactoryModuleBuilder.build(A.Factory.class));
}
}
```

Comment: Your problem seems to match the "Multiple factory methods for the same type" use-case in the [FactoryModuleBuilder docs](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html). Are you getting an error message, or do you have any other reason to believe this doesn't work?

Comment: @Jeff Bowman: I am getting an error message. I believe, we cannot have two AssistedInjects in one class.

Comment: Please paste in your exact error message; what you described should work, and any error would contradict the Guice documentation. (Also note that you have 'private' as a parameter modifier in your constructor parameter lists, which is not allowed.)

Comment: I am sorry, I did not realize I added private to the parameter, I fixed it.. I will paste the error.

Comment: Error: No implementation for Assistant$Factory was bound.
  while locating A$Factory

Assistant has more than one constructor annotated with @AssistedInject that matches the parameters in method Assistant$Factory.create().  Unable to create AssistedInject factory while locating Asisstant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fully allowed to have multiple `@AssisgedInject` constructors.

Your problem is you have two `@Assisted` parameters with the same type.  When this happens, you must write something like this to disambiguate them:

```
@AssistedInject
A(final Apple apple,
        @Assisted("raw") List<Fruits> rawFruits,
        @Assisted("ripe") List<Fruits> ripeFruits) {
}

public interface Factory {
    A create(@Assisted("raw") List<Fruits> rawFruits,
             @Assisted("ripe") List<Fruits> ripeFruits);
}
```

Comment: That worked. I was missing two things, @Assisted for one of the parameters in the constructor and the solution you mentioned. Thanks.